# VBA MACRO: Trying to edit a VBA Macro that returns json data

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, web-scraping

Please see the code below which works to query an api call. I show extracting only specific items from json. There is a lot more info returned e.g. all current employments which can be more than 1. How can the code be modified to query by state?

```
Option Explicit
'Individual
Public r As Long

Public Sub GetListings2()
    '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim json As Object, apiUrl As String, re As Object, s As String, latLon()
    r = 0
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    apiUrl = "https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/individual?hl=true&includePrevious=false&json.wrf=angular.callbacks._d&lat={LAT}&lon={LON}&nrows=100&r=25&sort=score+desc&{START}&wt=json"
    Dim xhr As Object, totalResults As Long, numPages As Long

    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    latLon = GetLatLon("30047", xhr, re)
    apiUrl = Replace$(Replace$(apiUrl, "{LAT}", latLon(0)), "{LON}", latLon(1))
    s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=0"), re)

    If s = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")

    totalResults = json("total")

    numPages = Application.RoundUp(totalResults / 100, 0)

    Dim results(), ws As Worksheet, headers(), i As Long

    'example info retrieved. There is a lot more info in json
    headers = Array("CRD Number Indiv", "Name", "FINRA registered", "Disclosures", "In industry since")
    ReDim results(1 To totalResults, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    results = GetIndividualListings(results, json("hits"))
    If numPages > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To numPages
            DoEvents
            s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=" & (i - 1) * 100), re)
            If s = "No match" Or InStr(s, "Exceeded limit") > 0 Then Exit For
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")
            results = GetIndividualListings(results, json("hits"))
        Next
    End If
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLatLon(ByVal zip As String, ByVal xhr As Object, ByVal re As Object) As Variant
    Dim json As Object, lat As String, lon As String
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", Replace$("https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/locations?query={ZIP}&results=1", "{ZIP}", zip), False 'changed results = 10 to results = 1
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("hits")("hits")(1)("_source")
        lat = json("latitude")
        lon = json("longitude")
        GetLatLon = Array(lat, lon)
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetApiResults(ByVal xhr As Object, ByVal apiUrl As String, ByVal re As Object) As String
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", apiUrl, False
        .send
        GetApiResults = GetJsonString(re, .responseText)
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetIndividualListings(ByVal results As Variant, ByVal json As Object) As Variant
    Dim row As Object
      'can have numerous current employments. Alter here and below if want more info from json about the individual

    For Each row In json
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = row("_source")("ind_source_id")
        results(r, 2) = Replace$(Join$(Array(row("_source")("ind_firstname"), row("_source")("ind_middlename"), row("_source")("ind_lastname")), ", "), ", , ", ", ")
        results(r, 3) = row("_source")("ind_approved_finra_registration_count")
        results(r, 4) = row("_source")("ind_bc_disclosure_fl")
        results(r, 5) = row("_source")("ind_industry_cal_date")
    Next
    GetIndividualListings = results
End Function

Public Function GetJsonString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal responseText As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\((.*)\);" 'regex pattern to get json string
        If .Test(responseText) Then
            GetJsonString = .Execute(responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetJsonString = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The results work but how can the query change to query against state instead of zipcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In a nutshell:**

Manually make a request for `Individual by State`, and for `Firm by State`, and observe the web-traffic via dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd>. In the network tab you will see the API calls made for each and observe the additional param `state` in the API call; and that the [angular](https://angularjs.org/) callback identifier changes. The API call returns json which, in the case of `Firm by State`, requires you to alter your paths for json parsing in order to get the local office.

---

**tl;dr**

You just add a `state` param into the queryString of the url. The value then used is the uppercase [2 letter code](https://www.factmonster.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes) for the state e.g. Louisiana = LA. The angular callback identifier also changes to reflect using state.

Still using LA as example....

The API call for individual becomes:

`https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/individual?hl=true&includePrevious=true&json.wrf=angular.callbacks._0&nrows=100&r=25&sort=score+desc&state=LA&wt=json`

And for firm:

`https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/firm?hl=true&json.wrf=angular.callbacks._1&nrows=100&r=25&sort=score+desc&state=LA&wt=json`

---

**Firm by state**

An example re-write for `firm by state` would be as follows:

<sub>Note: This extracts first local office address though main office is available in [json](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=8568b83b6e7f49619df13b794ddf4827). You also no longer need `LatLon`.</sub>

```
Option Explicit
'Firm by state
Public r As Long

Public Sub GetListings()
    '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim json As Object, apiUrl As String, re As Object, s As String, state As String
    state = "LA"
    r = 0
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    apiUrl = "https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/firm?hl=true&json.wrf=angular.callbacks._1&nrows=100&r=25&sort=score+desc&{START}&state={STATE}&wt=json"
    Dim xhr As Object, totalResults As Long, numPages As Long

    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    apiUrl = Replace$(apiUrl, "{STATE}", state)
    s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=0"), re)

    If s = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")

    totalResults = json("total")

    numPages = Application.RoundUp(totalResults / 100, 0)

    Dim results(), ws As Worksheet, headers(), i As Long
    ReDim results(1 To totalResults, 1 To 3)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("CRD Number", "Name", "Address")
    results = GetFirmListings(results, json("hits"))

    If numPages > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To numPages
            s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=" & (i - 1) * 100), re)
            If s = "No match" Or InStr(s, "Exceeded limit") > 0 Then Exit For
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")
            results = GetFirmListings(results, json("hits"))
        Next
    End If
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetApiResults(ByVal xhr As Object, ByVal apiUrl As String, ByVal re As Object) As String
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", apiUrl, False
        .send
        GetApiResults = GetJsonString(re, .responseText)
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetFirmListings(ByVal results As Variant, ByVal json As Object) As Variant
    Dim row As Object

    For Each row In json
        r = r + 1  'Crd number, name and local office address (not main branch)
        results(r, 1) = row("_source")("firm_source_id")
        results(r, 2) = row("_source")("firm_name")
        results(r, 3) = Join$(row("inner_hits")("branchOfficeLocations")("hits")("hits")(1)("_source").items, ", ")
    Next
    GetFirmListings = results
End Function

Public Function GetJsonString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal responseText As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\((.*)\);" 'regex pattern to get json string
        If .test(responseText) Then
            GetJsonString = .Execute(responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetJsonString = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Individual by state:**

```
Option Explicit
'Individual by state
Public r As Long

Public Sub GetListings2()
    '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim json As Object, apiUrl As String, re As Object, s As String, state As String
    r = 0
    state = "LA"
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    apiUrl = "https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/individual?hl=true&includePrevious=true&json.wrf=angular.callbacks._0&nrows=100&r=25&sort=score+desc&{START}&state=LA&wt=json"
    Dim xhr As Object, totalResults As Long, numPages As Long

    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    apiUrl = Replace$(apiUrl, "{STATE}", state)
    s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=0"), re)

    If s = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")

    totalResults = json("total")

    numPages = Application.RoundUp(totalResults / 100, 0)

    Dim results(), ws As Worksheet, headers(), i As Long

    'example info retrieved. There is a lot more info in json
    headers = Array("CRD Number Indiv", "Name", "FINRA registered", "Disclosures", "In industry since", _
                    "Employer CRD", "Employer Name", "Employer City", "Employer State", "Employer Zip")
    ReDim results(1 To totalResults, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    results = GetIndividualListings(results, json("hits"))
    If numPages > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To numPages
            DoEvents
            s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=" & (i - 1) * 100), re)
            If s = "No match" Or InStr(s, "Exceeded limit") > 0 Then Exit For
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")
            results = GetIndividualListings(results, json("hits"))
        Next
    End If
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub GetListings()
    '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim json As Object, apiUrl As String, re As Object, s As String, state As String
    state = "LA"
    r = 0
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    apiUrl = "https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/firm?hl=true&json.wrf=angular.callbacks._1&nrows=100&r=25&sort=score+desc&{START}&state={STATE}&wt=json"
    Dim xhr As Object, totalResults As Long, numPages As Long

    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    apiUrl = Replace$(apiUrl, "{STATE}", state)
    s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=0"), re)

    If s = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")

    totalResults = json("total")

    numPages = Application.RoundUp(totalResults / 100, 0)

    Dim results(), ws As Worksheet, headers(), i As Long
    ReDim results(1 To totalResults, 1 To 3)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("CRD Number", "Name", "Address")
    results = GetFirmListings(results, json("hits"))

    If numPages > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To numPages
            s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=" & (i - 1) * 100), re)
            If s = "No match" Or InStr(s, "Exceeded limit") > 0 Then Exit For
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")
            results = GetIndividualListings(results, json("hits"))
        Next
    End If
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetApiResults(ByVal xhr As Object, ByVal apiUrl As String, ByVal re As Object) As String
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", apiUrl, False
        .send
        GetApiResults = GetJsonString(re, .responseText)
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetIndividualListings(ByVal results As Variant, ByVal json As Object) As Variant
    Dim row As Object
      'can have numerous current employments. Alter here and below if want more info from json about the individual
    ' CRD Number, Indiv Name, FINRA registered, Disclosures, In industry since, _
    current employer firm ID, current employer firm name, current employer city, current employer state, current employer zip.
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each row In json
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = row("_source")("ind_source_id")
        results(r, 2) = Replace$(Join$(Array(row("_source")("ind_firstname"), row("_source")("ind_middlename"), row("_source")("ind_lastname")), ", "), ", , ", ", ")
        results(r, 3) = row("_source")("ind_approved_finra_registration_count")
        results(r, 4) = row("_source")("ind_bc_disclosure_fl")
        results(r, 5) = row("_source")("ind_industry_cal_date")
        results(r, 6) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("firm_id")
        results(r, 7) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("firm_name")
        results(r, 8) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("branch_city")
        results(r, 9) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("branch_state")
        results(r, 10) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("branch_zip")
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetIndividualListings = results
End Function

Public Function GetJsonString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal responseText As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\((.*)\);" 'regex pattern to get json string
        If .test(responseText) Then
            GetJsonString = .Execute(responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetJsonString = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr, it works like a champ! Now I just need to figure out how to pull in the current employer name, CRD# and address on the individual by state vba code

Comment: Note that, IIRC, from prior answer I gave to question on zip code search, there can be more than 1 current employer. So how are you planning on handling that? You’ll need to examine some of the data - I give links to Json in this answer and my prior. Decide what assumptions need to be made and desired output format.

Comment: Thanks Qharr! I've looked at the json data and I just want to pull in the info for the first current employer. firm_id, firm_name, branch_city, branch_state & branch_zip from the 1st inner hit.

Comment: Please indicate the final headers then for indiv by state.... I presume the headers you have just mentioned plus? CRD Number Indiv.... + .......

Comment: So i would like to keep the current headers for CRD Number, Indiv Name, FINRA registered, Disclosures, In industry since, current employer firm ID, current employer firm name, current employer city, current employer state, current employer zip. Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: m'kay....I will have a look quickly now.

Comment: Thanks @Qharr, it's perfect!

Comment: you are most welcome :-)

Comment: Hi @Qharr! Your previous solution was great!! Is there a way to automate or change the individual by state program to pull in a list of first names and last names or first name, last name & state or zipcode to run the api queries for that list and return the results for the names in the list? So there would be a separate file that contains the list of names to be queried against the site and that list needs to be pulled into the program variably to return the query results for those names/records.

Comment: Short answer is yes. I think I detailed in the prior anawer how to retrieve a record for an individual (though I never checked whether that info was vastly different from what you get in the individual by state/ individual only queries (which seems very detailed anyway). Look at both answers and try to put something together then post a question. Be sure to include your code, a couple of rows of expected output and explain where stuck. And show example inputs as well.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr posted new qeustion here https://stackoverflow.com/q/57927171/12016569?sem=2