# VBA Macro: Automating a VBA Macro that returns JSON data to query variable data

Tags: json, excel, vba, variables

Please see the code below which works to query an api call. How can the code be changed to pull in a list of variable data into the api call? Looking to have a separate list of first name, last name & zipcode pulled into the api calls and have the api call loop to pull in results into a spreadsheet? Sheet 1 will include data like this below but many rows:

```
Firstname      Lastname       Zipcode
John           Doe            55555
```

and will return the CRD # to the input data or multiple CRD #'s if there is more than 1 match

Output data would be the input data with CRD #'s attached like the below with no more than 3 for each record

```
Firstname      Lastname       Zipcode     CRD1      CRD2      CRD3
John           Doe            55555       xxxxxx    xxxxxx    xxxxxx
```

or returning the current results fields below would be fine as well

```
CRD Number Indiv    Name    FINRA registered    Disclosures In industry since   Employer CRD    Employer Name   Employer City   Employer State  Employer Zip
```

So for John Doe in 55555, the results would return the first result from the api call and look like this

```
CRD Number Indiv  Name          FINRA registered  Disclosures  In industry since  
9999999           JOHN, X, DOE  1                 N            9/9/1999           
Employer CRD  Employer Name  Employer City  Employer State  Employer Zip
9999          Company Name   New York       NY              55555
```

Here is current code

```
Option Explicit
'Individual
Public r As Long

Public Sub GetListings2()
    '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim json As Object, apiUrl As String, re As Object, s As String, latLon(), FNAME As String, LNAME As String, ZIPCODE As String
    r = 0
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    apiUrl = "https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/individual?hl=true&includePrevious=false&json.wrf=angular.callbacks._d&lat={LAT}&lon={LON}&nrows=12&query=FNAME+LNAME&r=25&sort=score+desc&wt=json"
    Dim xhr As Object, totalResults As Long, numPages As Long

    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    latLon = GetLatLon("ZIPCODE", xhr, re)
    apiUrl = Replace$(Replace$(apiUrl, "{LAT}", latLon(0)), "{LON}", latLon(1))
    s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=0"), re)

    If s = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")

    totalResults = json("total")

    numPages = Application.RoundUp(totalResults / 100, 0)

    Dim results(), ws As Worksheet, headers(), i As Long

    'example info retrieved. There is a lot more info in json
    headers = Array("CRD Number Indiv", "Name", "FINRA registered", "Disclosures", "In industry since", _
                    "Employer CRD", "Employer Name", "Employer City", "Employer State", "Employer Zip")
    ReDim results(1 To totalResults, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    results = GetIndividualListings(results, json("hits"))
    If numPages > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To numPages
            DoEvents
            s = GetApiResults(xhr, Replace$(apiUrl, "{START}", "start=" & (i - 1) * 100), re)
            If s = "No match" Or InStr(s, "Exceeded limit") > 0 Then Exit For
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("hits")
            results = GetIndividualListings(results, json("hits"))
        Next
    End If
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLatLon(ByVal zip As String, ByVal xhr As Object, ByVal re As Object) As Variant
    Dim json As Object, lat As String, lon As String
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", Replace$("https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/locations?query={ZIP}&results=1", "{ZIP}", zip), False 'changed results = 10 to results = 1
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("hits")("hits")(1)("_source")
        lat = json("latitude")
        lon = json("longitude")
        GetLatLon = Array(lat, lon)
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetApiResults(ByVal xhr As Object, ByVal apiUrl As String, ByVal re As Object) As String
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", apiUrl, False
        .send
        GetApiResults = GetJsonString(re, .responseText)
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetIndividualListings(ByVal results As Variant, ByVal json As Object) As Variant
    Dim row As Object
      'can have numerous current employments. Alter here and below if want more info from json about the individual
On Error Resume Next
    For Each row In json
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = row("_source")("ind_source_id")
        results(r, 2) = Replace$(Join$(Array(row("_source")("ind_firstname"), row("_source")("ind_middlename"), row("_source")("ind_lastname")), ", "), ", , ", ", ")
        results(r, 3) = row("_source")("ind_approved_finra_registration_count")
        results(r, 4) = row("_source")("ind_bc_disclosure_fl")
        results(r, 5) = row("_source")("ind_industry_cal_date")
        results(r, 6) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("firm_id")
        results(r, 7) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("firm_name")
        results(r, 8) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("branch_city")
        results(r, 9) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("branch_state")
        results(r, 10) = row("_source")("ind_current_employments")(1)("branch_zip")
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetIndividualListings = results
End Function

Public Function GetJsonString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal responseText As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\((.*)\);" 'regex pattern to get json string
        If .Test(responseText) Then
            GetJsonString = .Execute(responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetJsonString = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The current code returns the following fields

```
CRD Number Indiv    Name    FINRA registered    Disclosures In industry since   Employer CRD    Employer Name   Employer City   Employer State  Employer Zip
```

I'd like it to just return CRD numbers to the input variable data in sheet 1, the list of names & zipcodes or if easier just returning these same fields from the first query result on name & zipcode would work as well. Have tried to automate this to feed in the variable data from sheet 1 but continue to get many errors.

Comment: Hi @Qharr, this is the next phase of the project that is causing issues

Comment: why would there be more than one crd against an individual unless multiple indivs with the same name?

Comment: you should probably also make it clear what your current code returns and how what you actually want differs and explain what you have tried to do to solve it.

Comment: Edited Question @Qharr and yes there could be multiple indivs with same name but even if only the first crd can be added to the variable list of names and zipcodes that  would work too or just returning the current results and fields to the variable list of names and zipcodes would work as well.